# Try to use node.js, fs.read

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is how I am calling fs.read, but I'm continually getting an error. Is there something wrong here with my syntax?

The error on the command line is:  "errorCode": -1,

```
        var fs = IMPORTS.require('fs'), 
    sys = IMPORTS.require("sys")    

    var file=   this.filename, 
    start=  parseInt(offsetStart),
    end=    parseInt(offsetEnd);
    bufSize = 64 * 1024;

     fs.open(file,'r',0666,function(err,fd) {
          fs.read(fd,bufSize,0,end,start,function(err,str,count) {
              result = {    reply:str,
                        reply2:count            
                };}); });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might help if you explain what you are doing here. Why are you opening a file and what are you trying to read from it?

If it is a textfile it may be simpler to use a ReadStream something like this:

```
inp = fs.createReadStream('sample.txt');
inp.setEncoding('utf8');
inptext = '';
inp.on('data', function (data) {
    inptext += data;
});
inp.on('end', function (close) {
    console.log(inptext);
});
```

You might want to look at your code and ask yourself where the data in your return statement goes. If you really want to use a callback chain, you might try passing in an empty object, and then fill that with data, so that you don't have to worry about sending the data back up the callback chain.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I am reading an image (album art) from an mp3 file. So I offsets start and end which is the begin and end location of the img within the binary. The size of the data scraped could be as big as 100k and I am using base64 encoding.

Comment: I tried fs.createReadStream, but no matter what start,end or buffer parameter I set, it never reads more than about 57k worth of data. so I am getting a partial image.

Answer (score 1):

if you expect up to 100k and the buffer is 64k, and the image is offset, could it be getting the first 57K of something starting around 7k?

What happens if the bufSize is 256 * 1024?

Can the values of offsetStart and offsetEnd be displayed or dumped? They seem worth knowing.

Also, is the second value really an offset, or is it a length?

Comment: Hi Bill, the second value is indeed a `length` value. For example on reading gave me these figures: start:78889,end:138310.

Comment: Ah, and if you thought it was start and stop, you'd get a 'length' = 60K... not the correct 138310!  What happens if you change the code to match, and expand the buffer?

Comment: I just tried 256 * 1024, it still only a third of the image shows. I am wondering if there is a bug in this version of node v0.2.3. which I am obligated to use since it is part of the api that is built into the mobile platform I am developing for webOS.

Comment: Hmm, Thats a bummer. Same part of the image as with 64 * 1024? The 256 made no difference? Any reason not to try 4086 * 1024? 16 * 1024? Just to see if there is any sensitivity. What about a plain 4194304? If 4X from 64 to 256 didn't make a difference, probably that buffer is not the problem. It could always be a bug in the library.       Can you give it an image file about the same size that it appears to be reading?      I'm going to look for other examples of fs.createReadStream... and .js big files in general.

Comment: Have you seen the posting "What are the pros and cons of fs.createReadStream vs fs.readFile in node.js?" The writers agree that fs.readFile will load the entire file into memory, while as fs.createReadStream will read the file in chunks of the size you specify.

Comment: See also: http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs-dev/browse_thread/thread/f0da759fc2831265?pli=1